# Grant the root privilege to the application

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, sdp

I have an application which consists of the native part and higher
layer.

Therefore, it needs to be granted the root privilege to run some
native functions.

As the article I post before, I added a piece of code taken from Bluez
Utils(hidd.c).

```
if (bind(sk, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
    close(sk);
    return -1;
   }
```

The code has been built to be a .so by NDK.

Unfortunately, It keeps returning -1 and errno is 13 which means
Permission Denied.

Some experienced developers(Thank you here) mentioned about that the
error happens because this application doesnt have enough permission.

It "SHOULD NOT" be something like

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

I think this means you possess a system permission but your
application doesnt.
(Let me know if I am wrong)

Is there any way to grant the app for having the root privilege?

Any reply/clue/hint will be highly appreciated.

Regards-

Sam

Comment: guess not ..
you can do that only on rooted devices.

Comment: Hi Yes, my phone has been fully rooted.

Comment: Hi happy2Help, your approach seems cool. I will try it later and let u know if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i can help you with this.

Here we gooo...

```
void gainRoot()
{
    Process chperm;
    try {
        chperm=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
          DataOutputStream os = 
              new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/video0\n");
            os.flush();

            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();

            chperm.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is a function i normally use to change the permissions of root files.

When you do su, a new process will be created with root privileges. So using this Process you can do any root operations. There is some specific syntax that needs to be followed. Which is shown in the above example.

so one thing what you can do is build the bind part of the code as a separate executable and place it inside system/bin or at that place where normally executables are kept. Suppose the name of the executable is bind123 then instead of

```
            os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /dev/video0\n");
            os.flush();
```

replace it with

```
            os.writeBytes("bind123\n");
            os.flush();
```

in the above code.

This should work. Probably once this is working we can try integrating it with the application without any dependency on the executable. I hope i am not confusing you. If atall some clarity is neede, let me knowww.... ALL the best...

Comment: I will give it a short later. I seem understand your concept but yes, as you mentioned, how to integrate it with my application to gain the root permission is still unknown for me. watever, i will try your approach first.

Comment: Ok. As far as i know. Applications always by default run in the user mode. Even in Normal linux, it is like this. When you do su, a new process is created with UID 0. Which means it is a kernel process which has root previlages. Using this process, privileged tasks are performed. The same thing we are trying to here in Android App. If you want that your whole application should have the root permissions, i dont think there is that support available.

Comment: Hi happy2Help, in my case, bind() is the system call that I was hoping that I can use it to interact with my bluetooth. However, when my code executes to bind(), the error indicates permission denied. In the document, it explains this error as "The process does not have the appropriate privileges to bind local_address to the socket pointed to by socket_descriptor(for example, if socket_descriptor is a socket with an address family of AF_INET, and the sockaddr_in structure(pointed to by local_address) specified a port that wes restricted for use).

Comment: You mentioned "what you can do is build the bind part of the code as a separate executable and place it inside system/bin". I am not clear enough on how to implement it. Could you explain more specifically? Some really confuse me is that the same code does work on some phones but some dont. that's why I think this issue should get fixed. If you have any clue, please tell more. Thanks for your time and join this discussion.

Comment: Hi. Suppose if you want to execute helloworld program and execute it on android, how would you do it?
1) Write the program on your pc.
2) Using a cross compiler(You can use NDK) Build the Executable
3) Push the executable(ARM Binary) on to the platform(Android phone) inside /system/bin or
4) Go into the shell(adb shell), 
5) Run the executable(./myExe)
This should print helloworld.

In the same way instead of helloworld, you do bind operation and call the application from Application process.
First lets make sure tht this works. Then we can work for a more generic solution.. Hope its clear....

Comment: Thank you happy2Help. You are really warm-hearted. I got your explanation. This is much clear now.

Comment: Yes, I think my question got fixed!! Thank you happy2Help!! A reallllllly great idea!

Comment: cheers.. Just for your information if you want to make it more generic, you can include the executable inside the apk file. Yes you can do it but am not sure what is the procedure to be followed. I think inside Android.mk file, you need to modify stating BUILD_EXECUTABLE some thing like that. In that case your app can work without any problem on all phones.. Anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root to bind to port >=1024. You only need [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission in your [ApplicationManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file.

Comment: This piece of code is implemented for Bluetooth. Not for internet purpose.